# Find a counterexample to Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem for Q, the rationals

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Referencing the statement of BW: *Every infinite, totally bounded subset of M has a limit point*. Which is equivalent to *(M,d)* (a metric space) *is complete*.

Now clearly Q (with standard metric) is not complete as you can find a Cauchy sequence in Q whose limit is not in Q.

However, you would thus expect there to exist an infinite, totally bounded subset which has *no* limit point. But we couldn’t think of any, in fact it seems in general that all points in an interval are limit points, which seems fishy but we can’t see where it goes wrong (open sets are defined and Q is dense). So what such subset has no limit points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asked to prove that *there exists* an infinite, totally bounded subset $S \subset \mathbb Q$ with no limit point. And as you point out, $S$ is not going to be the set of points of $\mathbb Q$ in some interval. So you have to use what you know to come up with a better candidate for $S$.

You say you already know that there exists a Cauchy sequence $(x_n)_{n \ge 1}$ in $\mathbb Q$ whose limit is not in $\mathbb Q$. So now take $S$ to be the set of values of that sequence:
$$S = \{x_n \mid n \ge 1\}
$$
There's still something to prove, but that should be straightforward now --- you have to prove $S$ is infinite; and totally bounded; and has no limit point.